# Changing Form Size Via Screen Resolution

Tags: vb.net, resize, resolution

I've got a checkbox which resizes my form to reveal other settings, but it looks completely different on my display to my friends display. He is able to see way more than on my screen. He has a dual monitor desktop whereas I run on a laptop. I use this code -

Code:

```
Private Sub HuraCheckBox1_CheckedChanged_1(sender As Object) Handles HuraCheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If HuraCheckBox1.Checked = True Then Me.Size = New Size(1145, 642) Else Me.Size = New Size(409, 642)
    End Sub
```

If you need a photo of what I mean, I can provide one :)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to set the form size to ***show other controls***, IMHO let the form do its purpose and rethink your approach.

Comment: @Codexer Microsoft does that here and there.  Like an "Advanced" check box, which will expand the form and show more stuff.  Not my cup of tea, but that technique is out there.

Comment: These measures are subject to a number of considerations, the DPI awareness status of your application, for example. Anyway, a simple measure of the Screen size can be calculated using `Dim ScreenSize As Rectangle = Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds` or `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`. For more specific measures, see: [SystemParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You need to Import WPF PresentationFramework for this. Which itself could cause some weird behaviours sometimes.

Comment: @Codexer The "more options" I mentioned is actually just a webbrowser. In other words, the program uses an automated browser and when you tick the box it will show you what's happening in the browser.